# Convert white space to tabs

Tags: c

I recently decided to learn C, so I started going through K&R, but I got stuck on Problem 21 in Chapter 1. You are supposed to write a program, which given a string without tabs and a certain tabwidth, converts all white space into the equivalent spacing using tabs and white space.

So far, I've got this:

```
void entab (char from[], char to[], int length, int tabwidth)
{
    int i, j, tabpos, flag, count;

    j = tabpos = flag = count = 0;
    for (i = 0; from[i] != '\0' && j < length - count - 2; i++) {
        if (from[i] == ' ') {
            // If you see a space, set flag to true and increment the
            // whitespace counter. Don't add any characters until you reach the
            // next tabstop.
            count++;
            tabpos = (tabpos + 1) % tabwidth;
            flag = 1;
            if (count >= tabwidth - tabpos) {
                to[j] = '\t';
                j++;
                count = count - tabwidth + tabpos;
                tabpos = 0;
            }
        } else {
            if (flag == 1) {
                // if you see something other than a space and flag is true,
                // there weren't enough spaces to reach a tabstop. Add count
                // spaces to the string.
                flag = 0;
                tabpos = (tabpos + count + 1) % tabwidth;
                while (count > 0) {
                    to[j] = ' ';
                    j++;
                    count--;
                }
            } else {
                tabpos = (tabpos + 1) % tabwidth;
            }
            count = 0;
            to[j] = from[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    to[j] = '\0';
    return;
}
```

which, unfortunaly, seems to produce a slightly larger spacing than it's supposed to. Any ideas about where I screwed up?

PS I've looked at other solutions online and I understand that there is a much better approach to the problem, but I would really like to fix the error in mine as well.

EDIT: Setting tabwidth=4 and using:

```
    foobar
        foo  bar      foo bar
    foo     bar
```

as input, I get:

```
/t/tfoobar
/t/t/t/tfoo  bar/t/t/t foo bar
/t/tfoo/t/t bar
```

as output, while the correct output would be:

```
/tfoobar
/t/tfoo/t bar/t/t foo bar
/tfoo/t/tbar
```

Comment: As in a bug report: post what the input is, what you are getting, and what you are expecting. This would make it much easier for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (count >= tabwidth - tabpos)
```

This starts outputting tabs too soon. Consider the input string:

```
"aa              "
```

with 8 as tabwidth. You get to character 5 (i will be 4, count will be 3) when tabpos becomes also 5, therefore triggering the condition. You don't want to output tabs before your i variable reaches tabwidth.

I won't fix your code either. But instead of making general statements like "refactor your code" which is just a 21st century way of saying "rewrite your code", I can point out one obvious mistake. You don't need the tabpos variable. Just use (i % tabwidth). From here on things should start falling into place.

Comment: Given that this still draws interest, here's the fix. Get rid of tabpos completely. Change the suspect condition that I outlined to "if (i%tabwidth==tabwidth-1)" and change the subtraction from count in the condition's block to simply "count=0". For extra credit, solve the problem without introducing new variables (just an extra condition, really) in a way that won't replace single spaces with tabs even if the tab would jump just one.

Comment: "By get rid of tabpos" i mean, get rid of the declaration, initialization, and simply delete every line in your code that references it. Then make the two changes in my above comment, and it'll work. If you feel like putting some extra effort into it, solve the "extra credit" part.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure "&& count==0" will do it. "count" will never be zero there, you will have just incremented it a couple of lines ago. The droid you're looking for is "count > 1".

Comment: Gah typo, that's what I meant. ==1 for the special case.

Answer (score 4):

This much code in a single function and with that much nesting (four levels deep) is hard to get right and even harder to maintain.

I would suggest you first **refactor** what you have into more manageable pieces. For example:

- create a function called findTab that takes the string to test, the tab width (# of spaces) and returns the index of the first occurrence of a tab.
- Then create a function called something like replaceChars that takes the right of args and performs the replacement

Those are just a couple of ideas. What you will end up with is a handful of much shorter and much more manageable functions and most likely find your bug(s) along the way!

Btw, i tried a quick Google search for some C refactoring articles but alas came away empty handed. These days refactoring is all about OOP languages like Java, C# and C++. Still, a few rules of thumb will go a long way for you:

- Minimize nesting of code blocks: `if` statements and `for` & `while` loops
- Minimize the number of lines per function (within reason) keep it less than 60 tops
- (borrowed from OOP classes) make sure that each function does one very limited thing very well
- Name your variables and methods more verbosely - seems like a pain when you're doing it but it will pay dividends in the future, like now.

Good luck and welcome to SO!

Comment: While I agree with much of what you're saying in general, it almost seems like a non sequitur in response to this code. There are only 33 lines of actual code in this function, and only two levels of ifs. While the code could certainly be more readable, I think the main readability problem is not the length or complexity but the fact that many of the variables have meaningless names. eg: "flag" and "count" (What's being flagged? What's being counted?)

Comment: @Laurance: That is a good point. I should have included naming convention into my bullet list and will (if you don't mind.) And mentioning `ifs` only was an oversight. I meant all nesting, including loops, for which I count four deep.

Comment: Also, your suggested refactoring seems to be describing the inverse problem (replacing tabs with spaces, rather than replacing spaces with tabs).

Comment: @Laurance: It's true that 33 lines of code isn't bad but due to the nesting level a cyclomatic complexity calculation would defintely flag this function for refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that's extremely suspicious about your code is the way in which you increase tabpos. You increment it (mod `tabwidth`) for every space *twice*. Once after incrementing `count`, and again when `flag == 1`.

When debugging, especially code that has conditionals that affect future iterations of a loop,  it's good to think about invariants. These are statements that should always be true whenever you execute a particular line of code.

Another thing: give your variables better names. `flag` and `count` are especially bad, but `tabpos` is kind of confusing as well. My first thought was "the position of which tab?" but it appears that you actually want it to be the number of character-cells since the last tab-stop (or equivalently, your current position within a tab-column).

In any case, they should have clearer names. If the concept is too hard to name well then that may be a sign that you need to rethink your algorithm, or you should at least comment the variables. It's generally good to figure out invariants for variables too, like "tabpos is the number of character-cells since the last tab-stop" (which your code violates == bug).

Finally, you could try stepping through your code in a debugger, or even using printf debugging to see why it misbehaves on certain inputs.